# Continue reading apache receive buffer after inital handeshake for websockets

Tags: php, apache, websocket

Php Version: PHP 5.4.3 
Apache Version: 2.4.2

Im trying my hand at writing a simple websocket server. My question is how would I continue reading the server-side recieve buffer after the hand shake has been successfully made?

The webhost I'm using doesn't support php sockets, so creating a listener outside of apache+php is not an option, nor is changing webhosts at this time.

Comment: Can we see your code? Also, can't you just use [this](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php) (first Google result for `apache php websockets`) and save yourself the headaches? At least having a look at it and seeing how it does things might help you.

Comment: there's no code that really relates to this matter; basically I can get the client-request headers, preform the handshake, and send frames to the client, but I have no clue where to start to be able to read frames from the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the  architecture  of Apache, and possibly other HTTPd's, this isn't possible. Just software depends on a RESTful connection, in which the client requests data and then the server responses.

A websocket connection doesn't fit this format due to data being back and forth